# Change font size of a label using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Jquery:

```
$("#size").on('change',function(){
  var getValue=$(this).val();
  //alert(getValue);
  $("#lbll").css("font-size",getValue);

 });
```

HTML:

```
<select name="fontsize" id="size">
        <option id="size6">6</option>
        <option id="size8">8</option>
        <option id="size9">9</option>
        <option id="size10">10</option>
        <option id="size11">11</option>
        <option id="size12">12</option>
        <option id="size14">14</option>
        <option id="size18">18</option>
        <option id="size24">24</option>
        <option id="size30">30</option>
        <option id="size36">36</option>
        <option id="size48">48</option>
        <option id="size60">60</option>
        <option id="size72">72</option>
    </select>

<label id="lbll">fooo</label>
```

I want to change the font size of my label according to the selection of my dropdown list. I tried some methods but none of them seem to be working. Any idea whats wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you are missing `px` unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change code with this

```
<select name="fontsize" id="size">
    <option value="6px">6</option>
    <option value="8px">8</option>
    <option value="9px">9</option>
    <option value="10px">10</option>
    <option value="11px">11</option>
    <option value="12px">12</option>
    <option value="14px">14</option>
    <option value="18px">18</option>
    <option value="24px">24</option>
    <option value="30px">30</option>
    <option value="36px">36</option>
    <option value="48px">48</option>
    <option value="60px">60</option>
    <option value="72px">72</option>
</select>

<label id="lbll">fooo</label>
```

[Here the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maurosala/x4u62ofc/)

Answer (score 4):

You should specify a unit as shown below:

```js
$("#size").on('change', function() {
  $("#lbll").css("font-size", this.value + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="fontsize" id="size">
  <option id="size6">6</option>
  <option id="size8">8</option>
  <option id="size9">9</option>
  <option id="size10">10</option>
  <option id="size11">11</option>
  <option id="size12">12</option>
  <option id="size14">14</option>
  <option id="size18">18</option>
  <option id="size24">24</option>
  <option id="size30">30</option>
  <option id="size36">36</option>
  <option id="size48">48</option>
  <option id="size60">60</option>
  <option id="size72">72</option>
</select>

<label id="lbll">fooo</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. A few of your answer are working but best answer only can have one. So i had decide of giving to the lowest reputation user with an correct answer the best answer tick. Lets give everyone a chance, hope you can understand.

Comment: @yan It's always your chose which answer to accept, but it's better to keep your reasons secret and not say stuff like this because next time when you post a tougher question other users might ignore it because you won't accept their answer since they have some rep ;)

Comment: Thank you for your advice :) But not all question will have so many good answers.

Comment: Anyway, i said all this because i dont want anyone to misunderstood me. Or have any question in mind why their answer wasnt selected

Answer (score 1):

Add "PX" at last of value please see below JS -

```js
$("#size").on('change',function(){
  var getValue=$(this).val();
  
  $("#lbll").css("font-size",getValue + "px");

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="fontsize" id="size">
        <option id="size6">6</option>
        <option id="size8">8</option>
        <option id="size9">9</option>
        <option id="size10">10</option>
        <option id="size11">11</option>
        <option id="size12">12</option>
        <option id="size14">14</option>
        <option id="size18">18</option>
        <option id="size24">24</option>
        <option id="size30">30</option>
        <option id="size36">36</option>
        <option id="size48">48</option>
        <option id="size60">60</option>
        <option id="size72">72</option>
    </select>

<label id="lbll">fooo</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. A few of your answer are working but best answer only can have one. So i had decide of giving to the lowest reputation user with an correct answer the best answer tick. Lets give everyone a chance, hope you can understand.

Comment: Np, @yan I am not here to earn points I am here for helping others so glad to hear that answer is working for you :)

Comment: @YogeshSharma Thats the spirit! But points do encourage people in some ways too!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#size").on('change',function(){

        var getValue=$(this).val();


        $("#lbll").css("font-size",getValue + 'px');

     });
 });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ynf467fr/4/)

You have to add 'px' at the end of your font size.

Comment: Thank you for your help. A few of your answer are working but best answer only can have one. So i had decide of giving to the lowest reputation user with an correct answer the best answer tick. Lets give everyone a chance, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

you can't access the value without setting it in options, try replacing this..

```
<select name="fontsize" id="size">
        <option value="6px">Size 6</option>
        <option value="8px">Size 8</option>
        <option value="9px">Size 9</option>
        <option value="10px">Size 10</option>
</select>
<label id="lbll">fooo</label>
```

Here is the working **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/81ru0pve/2/)**.

Comment: Thank you for your help. A few of your answer are working but best answer only can have one. So i had decide of giving to the lowest reputation user with an correct answer the best answer tick. Lets give everyone a chance, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `px` to *text* being set as the CSS like so:

```
$("#size").on('change', function() {
  $("#lbll").css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r80mne7e/)

Comment: Thank you for your help. A few of your answer are working but best answer only can have one. So i had decide of giving to the lowest reputation user with an correct answer the best answer tick. Lets give everyone a chance, hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option id="size6" value="6">6</option>
```

modify all select list elements as above